# You don't have permission to access this resource [while deploying angular on apache]

Tags: angularjs, apache, docker, docker-compose

docker-compose

```
version: "2"

services: 
  django-apache2:
    build: .
    container_name: django-apache2
    ports:
      - '8005:80'
    volumes: 
      - ./www:/var/www/html/django_demo_app
      - ./angular/dist/ng7:/var/www/dist
      - ./demo_site.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

dockerFile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apt-utils \
    vim \
    curl \
    apache2 \
    apache2-utils

RUN apt-get -y install \
    libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

ADD ./demo_site.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY ./www /var/www/html
COPY ./angular/dist/ng7 /var/www/html/dist

EXPOSE 80
RUN rm /var/www/html/index.html
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/dist/index.html
CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

demo_site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dist

        Alias "/" "/var/www/html/dist"
        <Directory "/var/www/html/dist">
                Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>    
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I ran `ng build` and place build artifacts including index.html under `/var/www/html/dist`.

I'm getting Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. after hitting localhost:8005.

what am I missing here?

Comment: Try changing permissions of the /var/www/html/dist folder instead of index.html alone.

Comment: You also might delete the `volumes:` block, which will cause your host directory (and its permissions) to overwrite all of the setup that's getting done in the image.

Comment: I had some extra python config on my demo_site.conf. after removing it, it worked. Thank you for your help !